# How to find the file that triggered a FileSystemWatcher event

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

I'm using a FileSystemWatcher to check for changed files in a target directory. However it does not seem like I can access the information on what file triggered the event, or I do simply not know how.

```
$Action = {
    # Output name of trigger file here.
}

$FileSystemWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher $TargetDirectory
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher -EventName Changed -Action $Action
```

As I'm waiting for events in multiple target directories, the alternative of using synchronized waiting is no option for me.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think it's as simple as `Write-Host $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name`. Try it out.

Comment: It works, though curiously the event only seems to be triggered for directories which contents are changed. I'm only getting the name of the directory, not the name of the file that was moved, and no event in case of a file rename.

Comment: Seems like my error was that I expected the 'Changed'-Event to be triggered by path changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using this code:

```
$Action = {
    # Output name of trigger file here.
    Write-Host $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
}

$TargetDirectory = "c:\temp\fsw"
$FileSystemWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher $TargetDirectory
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher -EventName Changed -Action $Action
```

I get the full path of the file being changed.